# No audio input deviced are installed

Tags: windows-7, audio, input-device

If I go to Sound > Recording Devices and it says "No audio devices are installed"

If I click to set up a microphone I get an error
"Wizard could not launch, No audio input device found, make sure your audio hardware is working properly and check your audio configuration in the Audio Devices and Sound Themes control panel.

Where can I get an audio input device? I just want something so I can actually use the microphone on my headset. This is ridiculous. I have tried to look for any file but I simply cannot find a way to add an audio input device... I really do not want to format my computer just for this problem but I am starting to feel like that is the only option I have.

I have the latest chipsets

Comment: Post exact details please. "Latest chipsets" is not exact. Model numbers, version numbers (if applicable) please.

Answer (score 0):

You said you own a headset with an in-built microphone?

If that's the case, then you should have two 3.5 mm connectors attached to the headset cable. The one with a black (or sometimes green) outer casing is the one normally connected to the Line Out jack. You must connect the other 3.5 mm connector (usually pink in color) to the Mic In jack of your computer.

Check out [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/Connect-a-microphone-music-player-or-other-audio-device-to-your-computer) for more information on audio jacks and [this one](http://www.sound-recorder.biz/Tutorials_Recording_Recording_from_microphone.html) to learn which audio jack to connect to.